# Getting notification in the future which has been scheduled for specific dates

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am trying to set notification for specific dates in xamarin forms for android and I have already done it. My problem is if I schedule date for 26-5-2019 and install app in 27-5-2019 then on 27-5-2019 I also get the notification of 26-5-2019. I don't want to show notification if date is already gone.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(
   Forms.Context, 
   notificationId, 
   alarmReciver, 
   PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent
);

alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, nativeDate.Time,pendingIntent);
```

Comment: You need to check it at the time of install. Because you are setting alarm at the install time.

Comment: Isn't there any way to restrict notification from being displayed if date has gone ?

Comment: After set alarm that can not be possible to restrict! If you are looking for that way.

Comment: maybe you could get the current date when you install app first, then judge the current date and the expected date, use the alarmManager  when it is earlier than the expected time